# Rails - adding validations in observer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Hi i have state machine on my model and i need to add validations on observer. when i tried

```
def before_transition(record, transition)
  to = transition.to.to_s
  record.errors.add(:state, "Can't cancel") if to == 'cancel'
  return false
end
```

when i debug this with better_errors and binding_of caller gem i can see that errors adding to record.

```
>> record.errors.any?
=> true
```

But it is saving the record.

if i add before_update method to observer. which runs after before_transition method

```
def before_update(record)
  >> record.errors.any?
  => false       
end
```

error disappears.

How can i cancel update process for certain conditions in observers.

PS: I can't do it in model with validate method because i can't get transition in custom validator method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is right way to do it but i solved with

```
raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "There is an error"
```

I used as

```
def before_transition(record, transition)
  to = transition.to.to_s
  record.errors.add(:state, "Can't cancel") if to == 'cancel'
  if record.errors.any?
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "There is an error"
  end
end
```